Resampling and stutter - pulse audio
I have been fiddling with GQRX, an SDR radio piece of software that exports sound sampled at 48 kHz either directly to the local pulseaudio daemon or via UDP.
Issue is stutter in the speakers. Happens both locally on the Pi (3b) and on main PC when the audio data is UDP streamed:
$ nc -l -u -p 7355 | aplay -r 48000 -f S16_LE -t raw -c 1

Yields the said stutter accompanied by some buffer underrun messages. No more stutter / buffer underruns with:
$ nc -l -u -p 7355 | aplay -r 44100 -f S16_LE -t raw -c 1

Of course, the audio becomes distorted. Is there any way to fix my issue short of modifying GQRX ?
